# Why does my my input function print my else statement instead of the string i define?

Tags: python

The shell would won't let me define my input function without printing it.  I can add my If Else statement.  Why not?  Then when i ad my if/else statement is prints "not found"?
I'd like to have the if else statement inside of the input function.  Have a user input something from my dictionary and have it return the value.  Help! lol

Here is my code:

```
dictionary={"1":"mom","2":"dad","3":"son","4":"daughter","5":"newbaby"}

n=input ("Type a number:")
if n in dictionary:
    fam=dictionary[n]
    print(fam)
else:
    print("Not found homie.")
```

Comment: What does `python -V` tell you?

Comment: If you are using python 2, then you would need `raw_input` instead of `input`. In python 3, your code should work as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are running your code in the Python Interactive Shell. You have to open a new Python file, run your code, and then it should work. I just tested your code and it works fine in the IDLE.